# How to construct S3 URL for copying to Redshift?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I am trying to import a CSV file into a Redshift cluster. I have successfully completed [the example in the Redshift documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/gsg/rs-gsg-create-sample-db.html). Now I am trying to COPY from my own CSV file.

This is my command:

```
copy frontend_chemical from 's3://awssampledb/mybucket/myfile.CSV'
credentials 'aws_access_key_id=xxxxx;aws_secret_access_key=xxxxx'
delimiter ',';
```

This is the error I see:

```
An error occurred when executing the SQL command:
copy frontend_chemical from 's3://awssampledb/mybucket/myfile.CSV'
credentials 'aws_access_key_id=XXXX...'

[Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: The specified S3 prefix 'mybucket/myfile.CSV' does not exist
Details: 
 -----------------------------------------------
  error:  The specified S3 prefix 'mybucket/myfile.CSV' does not exist
  code:      8001
  context:   
  query:     3573
  location:  s3_utility.cpp:539
  process:   padbmaster [pid=2432]
  -----------------------------------------------;

Execution time: 0.7s
1 statement failed.
```

I think I'm constructing the S3 URL wrong, but how should I do it?

My Redshift cluster is in the US East (N Virginia) region.

Comment: I get the same error if I try the URL `s3://mybucket/myfile.CSV`, i.e. without `awssampledb`.

Comment: what does mybucket represent in your copy command?

Comment: Make sure that the path and the filename you are providing in the command actually exists. S3 internally uses the full path as the keyname (filename) so the full path should be exactly what you are using in your copy command. Use the AWS console to make sure the file exists at that path.

Answer (score 0):

The Amazon Redshift `COPY` command can be used to load multiple files in parallel.

For example:

- Bucket = `mybucket`
- The files are in the bucket under the path `data`

Then refer to the contents as:

```
s3://mybucket/data
```

For example:

```
COPY frontend_chemical
FROM 's3://mybucket/data'
CREDENTIALS 'aws_access_key_id=xxxxx;aws_secret_access_key=xxxxx'
DELIMITER ',';
```

This will load all files within the `data` directory. You can also refer to a specific file by including it in the path, eg `s3://mybucket/data/file.csv`